# How to clone a remote git repository with Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

In Eclipse the import command would accept a URI but in Android Studio import only seems to accept the location of a directory on my hard drive. How should I clone my remote repository with Android Studio?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to go to `VCS > Checkout from version control > Git/SVN/Mercurial`:

[image]

Comment: Great- that did exactly what I wanted. It appears there's no internal software downloads like in Eclipse so I had to install git from git-scm.com to make that command work. Thanks!

Comment: Any way to specify credentials?

Comment: This does not work with GITHUB, there is no way to specify credentials

Comment: @DavidePiras Hmm it worked for me. I'm currently using it with my Github account. This is the popup, that shows up for me: http://i.imgur.com/VPx3zhK.png

Comment: This doesn't work if you use GitHub with SSH, I have no idea how to make it work

Comment: It actually does - https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-push-to-a-remote-git-repository-over-ssh-with-privatepublic-key-authentication-using-android-studio/