# How do you install a custom library in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

What I want to do is reference this [Two Way Grid View library](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) and use the control in my project instead of the standard gridview.

It doesn't seem to be compiled in any way (can you compile java/android libraries?), so I tried creating a new project for it and then adding a reference to this project in the Project Structure window. This added the whole folder to the External Libraries node, but I can't seem to be able to reference anything in it.

I'm not sure that any of what I've tried is correct, so could someone step me through this (very basic) task? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597092/how-to-clone-a-remote-git-repository-with-android-studio) an answer describing how to clone libraries from github via android studio.

you than need to add reference this library to your project through:

```
File -> Project  Structure -> Modules
```

Comment: I've managed to get the activity_main.xml file to at least admit that the control exists, but then it won't show up in the designer, and the app crashes, saying:
The following classes could not be found:
- com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
Any way to get the UI to work properly?

Comment: @Miguel Have you fixed the issue. I'm having the same problem and don't know how to solve it.