# Custom Library Dependency Android?

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to add your own private custom libraries as part of the library dependency that comes built into Android Studio?

[image: Android Studio Library Dependency]

The idea is that this can be a way to deliver libraries from our mobile library team to our app development team quickly and easily.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but it certainly seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622410/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio-and-use-itsome-asked-dont. This, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657971/how-do-you-install-a-custom-library-in-android-studio.

Comment: yeah, i know the manual process was kinda hoping we can do the same thing this maven search does for custom libraries.