# Modify git hub downloaded source file?

Tags: android, github, arduino

I downloaded an android project's source file from github. It contain lot of folders. How can I open it in Android studio and modify it for my requirements in Android Studio. Its a app  to send bluetooth serial commands to arduino board.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a remote git repository with Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597092/how-to-clone-a-remote-git-repository-with-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the Github Repository from Android Studio itself, by providing your Github credentials. Please refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597092/how-to-clone-a-remote-git-repository-with-android-studio).

You need to navigate to `VCS > Checkout from version control > Git/SVN/Mercurial` where you will be promoted to enter your github credentials.