# Import GitHub project to Android Studio

Tags: android, import

I have problem with import android project Github in Android studio..

how the import download project "[Custom Tabs with Material Design effects](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs)" in Android Studio 1.4 ??

Download project Link : [Link](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs)

Comment: search for git tutorials (how to install git and clone remote repository) this is right link for repo https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs.git

Comment: check this question i think its the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597092/how-to-clone-a-remote-git-repository-with-android-studio?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
//...
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
}
```

And then you will be able to use the library.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597092/how-to-clone-a-remote-git-repository-with-android-studio)**

You have to go to `VCS > Checkout from version control > Git/SVN/Mercurial`